# Differance between getHeaderFields v/s getRequestProperties in HttpURLConnection in android

Tags: java, android, http, httpurlconnection

I was going through the [HttpURLConnection](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html) API doc and found two methods

`getHeaderFields ()` Which Returns an un-modifiable map of the response-header fields and values

and

`getRequestProperties ()` which also Returns an un-modifiable map of general request properties used by this connection.

I want to know what is difference between this two methods?

From My understanding both methods are used to store key,value pair in HTTP Header.

Correct me if I am wrong.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

`getHeaderFields()` returns all the fields and values while `getRequestProperties(String field)` returns the properties of the requested fields (not all).

Answer (score 0):

From < Android API 22 Platform > javaDoc:

> public Map<...> getHeaderFields ()
>   Added in API level 1
>   Returns an unmodifiable map of the response-header fields and values. The response-header field names are the key values of the map. The map values are lists of header field values associated with a particular key name.
>   Some implementations (notably HttpURLConnection) include a mapping for the null key; in HTTP's case, this maps to the HTTP status line and is treated as being at position 0 when indexing into the header fields.
>   Returns
>   the response-header representing generic map

And for request

> public Map<...> getRequestProperties ()
>   Added in API level 1
>   Returns an unmodifiable map of general request properties used by this connection. The request property names are the key values of the map. The map values are lists of property values of the corresponding key name.
>   Returns
>   the request-property representing generic map.